# Select method and with RemoveDuplicates method

Tags: excel, vba

So my first problem is I can't remove duplicates, error 424 vba object required appears.

```
Dim FinalRowE As Integer
Dim FinalRowK As Integer
Dim Cell As Range  'for later
Dim TabList As Range ' for later
Dim RawList As Range
Dim UnDuplicateList As Range

FinalRowE = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRowK = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

Set RawList = Range(Cells(FinalRowE, "E"), Cells(1, "E"))
RawList.Copy Range("K1")

Set UnDuplicateList = Range(Cells(1, "K"), Cells(FinalRowK, "K"))
UnDuplicateList.Select.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
       
End Sub
```

To see if my UnDuplicateList object was okey, I tried selecting the range like this:

```
Set UnDuplicateList = Range(Cells(1, "K"), Cells(FinalRowK, "K"))
UnDuplicateList.Select
```

The funny thing is that the first time I run the code it will only select the first cell ("K1") and only if I run the code for a second time in a row, it will select the hole range.

¿Any Ideas? I think I have all the objects declared.

Comment: you can't simply use `UnDuplicateList.Select.RemoveDuplicates` select doesn't return range. On the other hand `UnDuplicateList.RemoveDuplicates` works

Comment: Okey, so I fixed that and the first time it works great. I tried it a few times and it kept working. But on my 6th or so time running the code it stoped removing duplicates. I dont understand how that is possible. Do you know why?